# Extending Coldfusion CFFORM Validation with Custom JavaScript Validation

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

Does anyone know how to combine custom Javascript validation with the built in Coldfusion validation, so the custom Javascript alert is rolled into the same alert box as the CF one? I know CF adds an onsubmit event to the form and creates a _CF_check['name of form'] function to do some js validation, but how would I combine the alerts?

Comment: Depending on your needs, you might use `<cfinput onValidate="yourFunction" ..>` to call a custom javascript function.  Note: The signature of the javascript function must be `function yourFunction(formObject, formField, fieldValue)`

Comment: Unfortunately for various reasons I need to use a select instead of a cfselect for the custom js validation in a cfform.

Comment: You could still add a hidden field and hook your validation function into that. ie <cfinput type="hidden" onValidate="yourFunction" ..>. IIRC it will still be called when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you could use the `onValidate` attribute to call a custom javascript function. Not quite as elegant as using a cfselect (which you said you cannot use). But it does combine the alerts, and without hacking into the internal functions. If for some reason you cannot use onValidate, then you probably will have to dig into the internals.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function yourFunction(frm, fld, value){
        // some pointless validation
        var elem = document.getElementById('foo');
        return elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value == 2;
    }
</script>

<cfform name="theForm" method="post">
   <select name="foo" id="foo">
        <option value="0">apples</option>
        <option value="1">oranges</option>
        <option value="2">pear</option>
        <option value="3">grape</option>
    </select>
    <cfinput type="hidden" name="fooValidate" onValidate="yourFunction" 
            message="You must select pears because we say so..">
    <input type="Submit" name="txtSubmit">
</cfform>
```

Note: The signature of your javascript function **must** be:

```
  function yourFunction(formObject, formField, fieldValue) {
       ...
      // return true if validation was successful
  }
```

Comment: Oh I didn't think about doing it that way, perfect...thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you can do it is to just call CF build-in javascript function from your customized function like following code.

```
<script>
    function myFunction (_CF_this) {
        .....
        .....
        _CF_checkmyForm(_CF_this) // here is CF built-in function
        .....
        .....
    }
</script>

<cfform name="myForm">
    <cfinput name="txtInput" required="Yes">
    <input type="Submit" name="txtSubmit">
</cfform>
```

Comment: I do not think calling that function is the problem (it is already called automatically on submit). The issue is how to combine the javascript validation alerts into one.

Comment: @Leigh you are correct. Calling them is no problem, and they will both fire off (separately). The problem is the automatic CF one will be called and those alerts will be rolled into one alert box...if those pass then it checks my custom JS and opens yet another alert box...instead of one alert box for all.

Comment: @cam - See my answer. That is the simplest option I can think of without digging into the internals.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually moved away from using CFFORM's built-in validation mechanism, and CFFORM overall, by creating validation logic in CFC methods, and calling these remotely using `jQuery.ajax()`. This allows you to keep your validation in one place and enables you to use it for both client-side and server-side validation.